# Re-sort a result of reduced view

Tags: join, couchdb, reduce

consider the following document structures:

**Thread:**

```
 - doc_type   1
 - _id        
 - subject    (string)
```

**Posts:**

```
 - doc_type   2
 - _id        
 - thread_id  (_id of Thread)
 - time       (milliseconds since 1970)
 - comment    (string)
```

I need the threads sorted by the last post on a thread, together with latest 5 posts.
I thought to avoid updating the thread document every time a new post is done in order to eliminate probability of conflicts in a distributed environment across db nodes. Besides, it will be working for the DB where the DB should be working for you.

For simplicity - lets' just start with finding the latest post. The 5 posts can be gathered the same way.

Now, I'm not sure I'm on the right direction, however, looking [here](http://davispj.com/2008/10/02/couchdb-joins.html) I found how to find the last post in a thread using a reduce function that uses a group-level to return thread subject taken from doc-type 1, and the last post document taken from doc-type 2.

BTW - opposed to the sample in the link, in my case a thread is always created with a first post, (so, for example, the creation date of a Thread will be the date of it's first Post).

**map:**

```
function(doc){
  switch(doc.doc_type){
     case 1: emit([doc._id],doc); return;
     case 2: emit([doc.thread_id],doc); return;
  }
}
```

**reduce:**
on real world keys are more compound, so it must be used with appropriate group-level.
I also ignore here the case of re-reduce, just for simplicity's sake.
You can find full picture [here](http://davispj.com/2008/10/02/couchdb-joins.html):

```
function(keys, vals, rr){
   var result = { subject: null, lastPost: null, count :0 };
   //I'll ignore the re-reduce case for simplicity
   vals.forEach(function(doc){
      switch(doc.doc_type){
         case 1: 
            result.subject = doc.subject; 
            return;
         case 2: 
            if (result.lastPost.time < doc.time) result.lastPost = doc; 
            result.count++;
            return;
      }
   });
   return result;
}
```

But how do I **page** it afterwards sorted by the **latest-post date**?
Is there a way to feed doc-ids from a result of a query as the filter criteria of another (preferably, using one round-trip)?

There is no limit to the number of posts in a thread, so I'm a little reluctant to relay on list function here, when the page-size can also vary, what will result in the last post not showing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only after the last post or the last five posts, there's a much simpler method. You can completely avoid the reducer, in fact.

If you add the time as the second portion of the key, you can use a combination of endkey, descending, and limit to get the last N posts based on the thread_id.

Here's the MapReduce I wrote with some test data based on your schemas:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.type) {
    if (doc.subject) {
      emit([doc._id, doc.time], doc.subject);
      emit([doc._id, 'Z'], doc.subject);
    } else {
      emit([doc.thread_id, doc.time], {_id: doc._id});
    }
  }
}
```

The strange output of the 'Z' key is to allow you to get the subject from the "bottom" of the list of items.

The query parameters would look something like:

```
?endkey=["thread_id"]&descending=true&limit=6
```

The limit should be N+1 where N is the number of posts you'd like back. In the results you'll have the thread subject and _id objects (or whatever you'd like) from the post documents.

The _id objects are output in this example so you can use it with `include_docs=true` if you want the full post. Toss in whatever other data from the post document you want (title, etc) to keep the overall index size low and use include_docs in those places where you need the full contents of the document. However, if you always need the full post document, output it in the emit as that will give you a faster response (though a larger index size on disk).

Also, if you need a list of all threads sorted by last post as well as 5 posts per thread, you'd need to output keys like `[time, thread_id, 'thread']` and `[time, thread_id, 'post']` and use a `_list` to collect the posts "under" each thread document as the time sorting will cause threads and posts to be farther apart in the results. A `_list` function can then be used to combine/find them again. However, doing two requests may still be easier/lighter.

Comment: I understand how to use it to retrieve results of a given thread. But I must be missing something in your response - I don't understand how it helps me to get the threads sorted by the last post on a thread, together with latest 5 posts :(

Comment: Ah, so you're wanting a list of thread documents (or IDs) sorted by the time of the last post? What I've done above is focused on the post documents/ids of a single thread. If you need a list of all threads sorted by last post and 5 posts per thread, you'd need to output keys like [time, thread_id, 'thread'] and [time, thread_id, 'post'] and use a _list to collect the posts "under" each thread document as the time sorting will cause threads and posts to be farther apart in the results...the _list can be used to combine/find them again. But 2 requests may still be easier/lighter.

Comment: Well. that's what I was afraid of. Eventually I came to the same conclusion, but sought mind of experts, maybe there's a way to re-use output of the query of the IDs as input-filter for the view instead of doing it in two request... ...if you update your answer with what you say in the comments - I just might accept it :)

Comment: Updated my answer to include stuff we discussed here in the comments. Hope it's to your liking. :)

Comment: Great. I however edited the post - never relay on attributes to detect doc-type. 
That's why doc_type is for. 
Also - if you use descending, and you want the "bottom" of the list - you'd still use "startkey"

Comment: I see you reverted the edits...
the problem on relaying on attributes to determine doc-type is that it may lead to data-corruption and wrong results in views when new documents are introduced, and just might happen to have the tested attributes. Also - using descending and using endkey is an error, so   accept it like that would decieve other people.

Comment: @RadagasttheBrown for the attributes detection approach it really just depends on how you're managing your documents "schema." Using doc.type doesn't avoid the chance that the structure may change and get you different view results. Either approach is valid. Both take work, forethought, planning, and maybe a validate_doc_update.js just to be safe. :) It's really a matter of preference.

Comment: @RadagasttheBrown also the endkey thing is correct. startkey and endkey don't magically "flip" when you use descending. So if you were using startkey without descending, you'd get one result, and if you added descending, you'd not get the result inverted, you'd get an entirely different set of results. Give it a try. It's snagged me a time or two. :/