# couchdb - hook in changes-stream to manipulate documents

Tags: triggers, view, couchdb

Is there a way I can hook on the couch-db change-stream and use this events to manipulate documents?

Here's the thing:
following this issue
[couchdb - re-sort a result of reduced view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796377/couchdb-re-sort-a-result-of-reduced-view)

I'm trying another way of thought.
All I can do is use documents as source for views.

I can't re-sort a view, I can't use entries in reduced views as documents in a new view. 
But maybe I can turn them into documents (using some new doc-type for this purpose) and create views on these documents?

But even if I do it using some code external to the couchdb, this code will have to update the newly-generated documents every time any of the origin documents updates, and since I can be notified on updates using the update stream - maybe I should be using that? Sounds like a hack, will work though, but still a hack.

But - this one is for experts - if there is such a way that the update-stream will cause document modification using **any** mechanism **inside the couchdb** - then I can keep all this logic in the couch, and have it provide its services without external help.

Help anybody?

Answer (score 0):

The only CouchDB's internal "hook" is on updating a document and works only on one document (not necessarily the same but there are a lot of restrictions). See [`_update`](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers).

But what you describe can be done from the outside (with node.js for example).

Please note that triggering the update of several documents on the change of a document is probably a bad idea from a performance (and concurrency) perspective.

Comment: if I get it right, the _update works on the identified document, and cannot influence other documents. I'm looking for a way to update OTHER documents *from within the db*, saving the overhead of the transport between the couch and the node.